# Mongodb agregation match result is empty

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I have a Question table in MongoDB:

```
import { Schema, model, Types } from "mongoose";

const questionSchema = new Schema({ 
            question: {
                type: String,
                required:true,
            },
            topic_id: {
                type: Types.ObjectId,
                required:true,
            },
            explanation: {
                type: String,
                required:true,
            },
});
const Question = model("question", questionSchema);
export default { Question };
```

I want query with agregation (join more table) and find questions by topic_id:

```
import Question from "../models/Question";
const router = Router();

router.get("/topic/:topic_id", async (req, res) => {
    let result = await Question.Question.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { 'topic_id:': new Types.ObjectId(req.params.topic_id) }
        }]);
```

But result is empty. I don't understand why.

I made another query with QuestionAnswers table:

```
let result = await Question.Question.aggregate([{
    $lookup: { from: 'questionanswers', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'question_id', as: 'answers' }
}, {
    $match: { 'answers.isValid': false }
}]);
```

But answers array containts the valid answers. Why? Please help me.

Comment: Why are you doing `Question.Question.aggregate`? What exactly is `Question`?

Comment: I know find is simplifier then aggregate but I want extend the aggregation later.

Comment: `$match: { 'topic_id:': new Types.ObjectId(req.params.topic_id) }` you have `:` inside your key

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. please post code.

Comment: You are searching like this 'topic_id:' it should be 'topic_id'